# Notepad ++ Launch in Chrome equivalent in Atom

Tags: atom-editor

Do we have *'Launch in Chrome'* equivalent in Atom. Screen shot of a similar functionality in **Notepad++** is below:

[image: Notepad ++ - **Launch in Chrome**]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several packages for Atom. E.g.

- https://atom.io/packages/open-in-browser
  opens a file in the default browser
- https://atom.io/packages/open-in-browsers
  a more configurable package where you can choose a browser

just to mention two of them, there are [several more](https://atom.io/packages/search?q=browser) if you search the Atom packages site.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way that I have figured out how to open a file in your browser, is to right click the file that you desire to open on the left hand side of Atom, and click "Copy full path".

After you do that, just paste the full path into whichever browser you're using, and then you have your file opened in the browser.

This is the easiest way that I have found to do it. The packages seem to not want to work well for me.